# Bootstrap popover to appear on hover and remain for a second

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I would like a popover to appear on hover, but to remain only if the user is interacting with it (it contains links) if not, it should disappear after 500ms.

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').popover({ title: 'Look! A bird!', html:true, delay: { show: 100, hide: 1000 } });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<button type="button" class="badge btn btn-default" data-trigger="click" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html=true data-content="@foreach($tag->tracks as $track) <a href='/tracks/{{ $track->mdbid }}'>{{ $track->title }}</a> @endforeach">{{ $tag->tracks->count() }}</button>
```

Ignore the funny code inside the brackets (It is Laravel blade syntax)

**JSFiddle**

I have created this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WP2xf/1/) although it doesn't work properly (it does on my machine). I have got the delay working. However, if the mouse is within the popover, it still disappears. How can I prevent this and make it only disappear when the mouse it outside the popover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### THIS IS NOT MY WORK, I DO NOT KNOW WHO THE ORIGINAL AUTHOR IS BUT ALL CREDIT GOES TO THEM

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WojtekKruszewski/Zf3m7/22/) solved it.

**HTML**

```
<p id='container'>
<button class='btn btn-primary btn-large' data-popover="true" data-html=true data-content="<a href='http://www.wojt.eu' target='blank' >click me, I'll try not to disappear</a>">hover here</button>
</p>
```

**Javascript**

```
var originalLeave = $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.leave;
$.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.leave = function(obj){
  var self = obj instanceof this.constructor ?
    obj : $(obj.currentTarget)[this.type](this.getDelegateOptions()).data('bs.' + this.type)
  var container, timeout;

  originalLeave.call(this, obj);

  if(obj.currentTarget) {
    container = $(obj.currentTarget).siblings('.popover')
    timeout = self.timeout;
    container.one('mouseenter', function(){
      //We entered the actual popover – call off the dogs
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      //Let's monitor popover content instead
      container.one('mouseleave', function(){
        $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.leave.call(self, self);
      });
    })
  }
};


$('body').popover({ selector: '[data-popover]', trigger: 'click hover', placement: 'auto', delay: {show: 50, hide: 400}});
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 8em 3em;
}
```